# implementing one to many relationship encourage this exception: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

I have two entity classes which have one to many relationship. Suggestion and suggestionScope classes. (1 suggestion has one suggestion scope but 1 suggestion scope is used in many suggestion) Now I want to implement it using jpa. I implemented it like this:

```
public class Suggestion {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SUGGESTION_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SUGGESTION_SEQ", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SUGGESTION_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR")
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id; 

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_SUGGESTION_SCOPE")
    @XmlElement(name = "FK_SUGGESTION_SCOPE")
    private SuggestionScope suggestionScope;

    ...

}
```

this is the child side and in parent side I have not used any relational annotation, but when I try to run it, I get this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object
>   was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST:
>   SuggestionScope{id=null, name='null'}.

I have added this part to child side:

```
@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_SUGGESTION_SCOPE")
@XmlElement(name = "FK_SUGGESTION_SCOPE")
private SuggestionScope suggestionScope;
```

by the time I run it, it is like one to one relation!!; for each record of child table it is persisting one parent also!

thanks in advance

Comment: Show some code where you are persisting your children.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan suggestionDao.create(suggestion);

Comment: No i mean that `create()` method where you are setting up your relations.

Comment: it is my create method: public T create(T t) {
        try {

            getEntityManager().persist(t);
            getEntityManager().flush();
            getEntityManager().refresh(t);

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }